# Some guidance on how to start as a freelance Web Designer

Tags: freelance-websites

I am pretty proficient with WordPress, I can make very good looking sites using heavily modified Themes, my camera and Photoshop.

I never thought my skills in website making could be worth a dime because it always have been a hobby to me, but I found out that people make good money by making WordPress sites. So I decided to try to sell my skills and make a website for someone, but I don't know anything about this world! So these are my questions:

When I've made the site, how can I "give" it to the person paying me? Have I to give them credentials and hosting account and stuff or I keep those and also must maintain their sites?

If they want "dynamic" content (think about a restaurant wanting to give information about menu changes twice a month or something like this) and they are completely ignorant about computers, how can I maintain their site? How much can I charge for a site, considering that I can do visually appealing things with good SEO and original reflex photographies (I take some think like 30 hours to make a nice site)?

I'm sorry if my questions are incorrect but I'm new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything is possible in contracts.

You can have your hosting and give them (limited access) credentials or you can put the site on the customers hosting.

You can ask for a one time fee or make a contract for maintaining and updating the site.

You have to find your price which heavily depends on the region and job (so google for that) and then usually the price is calculated on the time you expect to need. You might even make a contract where they pay you per hour.

If you just start this, you should read about responsibilities as contractor so that you are not surprised if something happens.